# cygwin and python just don't work?

Tags: windows-7, python, cygwin

I've tried using the current version of cygwin python, but attempting to use pip or easy_install results in an error message about being unable to load DLLs (I won't reproduce it here because I removed that version of python).

I've tried compiling python under cygwin, but that ends with this error:

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not fo
und:
_bsddb             _curses            _curses_panel
_sqlite3           _ssl               _tkinter
bsddb185           bz2                gdbm
linuxaudiodev      nis                ossaudiodev
readline           spwd               sunaudiodev
zlib
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module'
s name.


Failed to build these modules:
_io

running build_scripts
```

What is the recommended way of having a working python installation under cygwin on Windows 7?

Comment: why do you insist on cygwin?

Comment: I believe @akira is asking why you want to use CygWin Python instead of native Windows Python. It's a fair question.

Comment: @CarlF: Because I general prefer to work in a posix-ish environment, and windows python doesn't play nicely with unix-like paths. Plus, windows is a special case for so many python tools and libraries.

Comment: @Marcin: can you give an example of a problematic path that does not work on the native windows port of python?

Comment: @akira: Literally any path with forward slashes in it will break python-based tools.

Comment: `import os; print os.listdir("/User/akira/Documents")` works just fine. windows accepts both \ and / as path separator, so i dont see any underlying issue there.

Comment: @akira: Are you being deliberately unhelpful? I am talking about tools that are invoked using the shell.

Comment: @Marcin: i ve worked for years on windows, with and without cygwin, with and without python / ruby / pure c/c++ programs; i ve also worked for years on porting stuff from unix to windows and back. thus i doubt that there are _real_ problems with the paths. and asking stuff out of curiosity is not "unhelpful"; it's just that: asking.

Comment: @akira: You *doubt* there are problems? If your experience were as impressive as you seem to want me to believe it to be, I think you would *know*.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the recommended way of having a working python installation
>   under cygwin on Windows 7?

I've used easy_install with Cygwin Python without a problem on Windows 7 64-bit, so perhaps the Cygwin port has improved in the 1.5 years since this question was originally asked. I've also used the Windows installation of Python from Cygwin (with a healthy dose of cygpath() ); this can be a pain but it may be easier than porting each version of Python to work with Cygwin yourself, and it allows you to use one Python for Windows and Cygwin invocations.

I'd recommend that anyone reading this question today who wants to use Python with Cygwin try the Cygwin packages for Python first, and fall back to Windows Python only if required. easy_install is part of setuptools and requires [manual installation outside of the Cygwin package manager](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#cygwin-mac-os-x-linux-other), but it does everything I've asked it to without a problem. I've not used pip on Cygwin. It does seem like all non-Cygwin package/module managers (e.g., cpan) sometimes result in the need for occasional manual executions of "rebaseall" on Windows 7, but I'd say it is still easier than using the Window Python + cygpath workaround.